# How to add to a list in C# Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

As I'm iterating through the properties of a generic object, I may find a `List<T>`.

So far, I've been able to initialize the list, but I can't seem to get **how to get the list type, initialize the object, put data into it, then finally add to the list ?**

Here's the code, and where i'm stuck:

```
private static void FillMePlease<T>(T genericThingy)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in genericThingy.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(genericThingy, "Test", null);
        }
        else
        {
            //var list = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            //Now I'm stumped.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how the different bits of your question fit together, so here are hopefully some pointers.

To see whether a Type is a `List<T>`:

```
type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
```

To get the `T` in a `List<T>`:

```
elementType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

To construct the type of a `List<T>`, given only the `T`:

```
typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType)
```

To add an item to a `List<T>` using reflection:

```
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Add");
methodInfo.Invoke(list, new object[] { itemToAdd });
```

Comment: Spot on. What I noticed was missing in related SO questions was how to get the `T` in `List<T>`. Thanks for being lightning fast to answer, as well. Have a nice day!